# use SOAP for laravel authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, soap

I am using a SOAP interface as a way of dealing with data on a legacy system. I need to validate users using the information in this system.  I found the following as part of a Laravel (5.,4) installation

**app\config\auth.php**

> ```
> | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
> | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
> | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
> ```

I made a demo of SOAP working in Laravel (so it data does fetch from then needed table). I used this: https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap  It seems to work so far ...

For the authentication system, what changes do I need to make in Laravel so that it will recognize a rows retrieved from SOAP and not a row fetched from the DB?
TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try this package http://github.com/ACFBentveld/Soap it is much easier to use and mostly faster. For your auth you have to create a new provider. In the Auth config you can define which providers laravel uses to authenticate users.

For more information see

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers
https://devmarketer.io/learn/setting-multi-authentication-laravel-5-4-part-1/